# iconv separates accents from letter when using libiconv

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv

I'm trying to make a function that would return a given string without its accents, but iconv's `//TRANSLIT` option only seems to separate the accent and the letter without removing the accent.

Here's my function :

```
<?php
function strRemoveAccents($str)
{
    return iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);
}
```

And here are my results :

- test 1

  - Input : Athènes
  - Expected output : Athenes
  - Current output : Ath`enes
- test 2

  - Input : Gdańsk
  - Expected output : Gdansk
  - Current output : Gda'nsk
- test 3

  - Input : niño
  - Expected output : nino
  - Current output : ni~no

Some precisions :

- `mb_detect_encoding` returns 'UTF-8' for all of my tests, and replacing the function with its return does not change anything.
- My locale is currently set to `LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C`
- I also tried changing the locale to `en_US.UTF-8` (I checked : the locale was successfully updated), but the function's return was still the same
- Tested on a Macbook with the default locale set to `c/fr_FR.UTF-8/c/c/c/c` the problem is still the same.
- I could remove the accents, but since I'll be using the method on whole sentences, I don't want to remove more apostrophes than needed.
- Edit : when testing with [this sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), I get the results I want.

I'm probably missing something, but I don't see what.

Edit : As mentioned by @jasonwubz on his answer, the problem is only present when using **libinconv**, and not when using **glibc**. Is there a way to make it work when using any of these implementations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the diacritics is that they are processed differently according to the language, for example in Arabic, diacritics are considered a character that has it's own Unicode code point, and when they join the Arabic letters they still a different character than the parent letter, for example this is a Meem letter `"م"` and this is a Dammah Diacritic `"ُ"` when the Dammah joins the Meem they will be **2 characters** in the string. [That is why you can post *nearly* empty posts on SE network with these types of diacritics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271986/arabic-diacritic-unicode-characters-break-title-links)

so removing these diacritic from a string is as simple as searching for these ~8 diacritic and replace them with empty string, while keeping the parent letters untouched.

```
$withoutDiacritic = str_replace(['ٌ','ُ','ً','َ','ٍ'], "", $string);
```

The problem with the Latin characters is different, when a diacritic joins a letter they produce 1 letter character  with it's own Unicode code point. For example when you join a diacritic to the letter `"e"` it will be converted to another Unicode character `"è"` so you can't apply what we do in Arabic diacritics by searching for the diacritics and removing them, instead you must search for `"è"` character and replace it with `"e"`, and that is what [node diacritics](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-diacritics) does.

I made a PHP version of [node diacritics](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-diacritics) , *don't forget to star these guys as they did all the heavy lifting*.

```
<?php

namespace PHPDiacritics;

class PHPDiacritics
{

    protected $replacementList = [
        ["base" => " ", "chars" => '"\u00A0"'],
        ["base" => "0", "chars" => '"\u07C0"'],
        ["base" => "A", "chars" => '"\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F"'],
        ["base" => "AA", "chars" => '"\uA732"'],
        ["base" => "AE", "chars" => '"\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2"'],
        ["base" => "AO", "chars" => '"\uA734"'],
        ["base" => "AU", "chars" => '"\uA736"'],
        ["base" => "AV", "chars" => '"\uA738\uA73A"'],
        ["base" => "AY", "chars" => '"\uA73C"'],
        ["base" => "B", "chars" => '"\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0181"'],
        ["base" => "C", "chars" => '"\u24b8\uff23\uA73E\u1E08\u0106\u0043\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u0187\u023B"'],
        ["base" => "D", "chars" => '"\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018A\u0189\u1D05\uA779"'],
        ["base" => "Dh", "chars" => '"\u00D0"'],
        ["base" => "DZ", "chars" => '"\u01F1\u01C4"'],
        ["base" => "Dz", "chars" => '"\u01F2\u01C5"'],
        ["base" => "E", "chars" => '"\u025B\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E\u1D07"'],
        ["base" => "F", "chars" => '"\uA77C\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B"'],
        ["base" => "G", "chars" => '"\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E\u0262"'],
        ["base" => "H", "chars" => '"\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D"'],
        ["base" => "I", "chars" => '"\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197"'],
        ["base" => "J", "chars" => '"\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248\u0237"'],
        ["base" => "K", "chars" => '"\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2"'],
        ["base" => "L", "chars" => '"\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780"'],
        ["base" => "LJ", "chars" => '"\u01C7"'],
        ["base" => "Lj", "chars" => '"\u01C8"'],
        ["base" => "M", "chars" => '"\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C\u03FB"'],
        ["base" => "N", "chars" => '"\uA7A4\u0220\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u019D\uA790\u1D0E"'],
        ["base" => "NJ", "chars" => '"\u01CA"'],
        ["base" => "Nj", "chars" => '"\u01CB"'],
        ["base" => "O", "chars" => '"\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C"'],
        ["base" => "OE", "chars" => '"\u0152"'],
        ["base" => "OI", "chars" => '"\u01A2"'],
        ["base" => "OO", "chars" => '"\uA74E"'],
        ["base" => "OU", "chars" => '"\u0222"'],
        ["base" => "P", "chars" => '"\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754"'],
        ["base" => "Q", "chars" => '"\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A"'],
        ["base" => "R", "chars" => '"\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782"'],
        ["base" => "S", "chars" => '"\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784"'],
        ["base" => "T", "chars" => '"\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786"'],
        ["base" => "Th", "chars" => '"\u00DE"'],
        ["base" => "TZ", "chars" => '"\uA728"'],
        ["base" => "U", "chars" => '"\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244"'],
        ["base" => "V", "chars" => '"\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245"'],
        ["base" => "VY", "chars" => '"\uA760"'],
        ["base" => "W", "chars" => '"\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72"'],
        ["base" => "X", "chars" => '"\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C"'],
        ["base" => "Y", "chars" => '"\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE"'],
        ["base" => "Z", "chars" => '"\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762"'],
        ["base" => "a", "chars" => '"\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250\u0251"'],
        ["base" => "aa", "chars" => '"\uA733"'],
        ["base" => "ae", "chars" => '"\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3"'],
        ["base" => "ao", "chars" => '"\uA735"'],
        ["base" => "au", "chars" => '"\uA737"'],
        ["base" => "av", "chars" => '"\uA739\uA73B"'],
        ["base" => "ay", "chars" => '"\uA73D"'],
        ["base" => "b", "chars" => '"\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253\u0182"'],
        ["base" => "c", "chars" => '"\uFF43\u24D2\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184"'],
        ["base" => "d", "chars" => '"\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\u018B\u13E7\u0501\uA7AA"'],
        ["base" => "dh", "chars" => '"\u00F0"'],
        ["base" => "dz", "chars" => '"\u01F3\u01C6"'],
        ["base" => "e", "chars" => '"\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u01DD"'],
        ["base" => "f", "chars" => '"\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192"'],
        ["base" => "ff", "chars" => '"\uFB00"'],
        ["base" => "fi", "chars" => '"\uFB01"'],
        ["base" => "fl", "chars" => '"\uFB02"'],
        ["base" => "ffi", "chars" => '"\uFB03"'],
        ["base" => "ffl", "chars" => '"\uFB04"'],
        ["base" => "g", "chars" => '"\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\uA77F\u1D79"'],
        ["base" => "h", "chars" => '"\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265"'],
        ["base" => "hv", "chars" => '"\u0195"'],
        ["base" => "i", "chars" => '"\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131"'],
        ["base" => "j", "chars" => '"\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249"'],
        ["base" => "k", "chars" => '"\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3"'],
        ["base" => "l", "chars" => '"\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747\u026D"'],
        ["base" => "lj", "chars" => '"\u01C9"'],
        ["base" => "m", "chars" => '"\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F"'],
        ["base" => "n", "chars" => '"\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5\u043B\u0509"'],
        ["base" => "nj", "chars" => '"\u01CC"'],
        ["base" => "o", "chars" => '"\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\uA74B\uA74D\u0275\u0254\u1D11"'],
        ["base" => "oe", "chars" => '"\u0153"'],
        ["base" => "oi", "chars" => '"\u01A3"'],
        ["base" => "oo", "chars" => '"\uA74F"'],
        ["base" => "ou", "chars" => '"\u0223"'],
        ["base" => "p", "chars" => '"\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755\u03C1"'],
        ["base" => "q", "chars" => '"\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759"'],
        ["base" => "r", "chars" => '"\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783"'],
        ["base" => "s", "chars" => '"\u24E2\uFF53\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B\u0282"'],
        ["base" => "ss", "chars" => '"\u00DF"'],
        ["base" => "t", "chars" => '"\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787"'],
        ["base" => "th", "chars" => '"\u00FE"'],
        ["base" => "tz", "chars" => '"\uA729"'],
        ["base" => "u", "chars" => '"\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289"'],
        ["base" => "v", "chars" => '"\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C"'],
        ["base" => "vy", "chars" => '"\uA761"'],
        ["base" => "w", "chars" => '"\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73"'],
        ["base" => "x", "chars" => '"\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D"'],
        ["base" => "y", "chars" => '"\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF"'],
        ["base" => "z", "chars" => '"\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763"']
    ];

    protected $chars = [];

    protected $encoding;

    public function __construct($encoding = "")
    {
        if (!$encoding) $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
        if (!$encoding) $encoding = 'UTF-8';
        /*
         *you can filter the encodings here with the supported encodings of mb_* functions
         *https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php
         *but I will leave mb_* functions generate error of level E_WARNING if unsupported encoding is used
         */
        $this->encoding = $encoding;

        //$charsCountTotal = 0; // for debugging
        //build the indexed array chars for better performance
        foreach ($this->replacementList as $replacementList){
            $charsString = json_decode($replacementList["chars"]);
            //if(!$charsString) die('noooooooooooooooooo'); // debugging
            $charsCount = mb_strlen($charsString, $this->encoding);
            //$charsCountTotal += $charsCount; // for debugging
            for($i = 0; $i < $charsCount; $i++){
                $char = mb_substr($charsString, $i, 1, $this->encoding);
                $this->chars[$char] = $replacementList["base"];
            }
        }
        //echo "chars count" . $charsCountTotal . "\n"; // for debugging
        //echo "array count" . count($this->chars) . "\n"; // for debugging

    }

    public function removeDiacritics($string)
    {

        $finalString = "";
        $charsCount = mb_strlen($string, $this->encoding);
        for($i = 0; $i < $charsCount; $i++){
            $char = mb_substr($string, $i, 1, $this->encoding);
            $finalString .= !empty($this->chars[$char]) ? $this->chars[$char] : $char;
        }
        return $finalString;
    }




}
```

Using the class

```
$phpDiacritics = new PHPDiacritics('UTF-8');

$test1 = "Athènes";
$test2 = "Gdańsk";
$test3 = "niño";

echo $phpDiacritics->removeDiacritics($test1) . "\n";
echo $phpDiacritics->removeDiacritics($test2) . "\n";
echo $phpDiacritics->removeDiacritics($test3) . "\n";
```

This outputs

```
Athenes
Gdansk
nino
```

Comment: That seems very nice, thanks ! Do you have also a github implemetation of this class ? Can I use it in a public github project ?

Comment: You are welcome, in case you couldn't solve your iconv problem, this is another option

Comment: @MarcBrillault No I didn't put it on github, and sure do what ever you wanna do with it

Comment: What account of yours do you want it to be linked to, if any ?

Comment: @MarcBrillault Thanks, no need for that I don't use GitHub much. You can link to the original [NodeDiacritics](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-diacritics)

Comment: I won't forget to do so.

Answer (score 5):

The PHP sandbox's iconv is using a glibc implementation. You can find out what implementation your one is using by doing a `var_dump(ICONV_IMPL)` If you want to get the same behavior then you just need to recompile PHP with the new glibc implementation. See link https://www.php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php

Then again, that is an overkill, and you can simply use `strtr` instead. This example comes from PHP.net

```
$addr = strtr($addr, "äåö", "aao");
```

Comment: hi @jasonwubz, and thanks for your answer (sorry for the delay). I'll check the iconv configuration on my host, maybe the issue won't be present when live.
As for a simple search and replace, that won't be easy since I want to manage all the possibilities : I'd have to list every possible character and that won't be a short list. Iconv does perfectly the job, minus this little disapointment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short and sweet answer is "No".  [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Other-iconv-Implementations.html#Other-iconv-Implementations) is a bit of (well-deserved) Gnu propaganda.  I think the glibc implementation is just better.  If you are stuck with libiconv, here is another alternative which doesn't require enumerating all of the diacritical characters:

Replace the actual punctuation characters (viz '~` etc) with non-appearing strings (like @@@hexcode@@@), then do the transliteration, then strip the punctuation marks and translate the non-appearing strings back to punctuation.  That way you only have to worry about the ascii punctuation marks, and not the entire utf-8 character set.  It's a little ugly, but I think it gets the job done.  That should work regardless of whether you find yourself with glibc or libiconv.